# How can I have a ripple on click and an other foreground on a selected cardview?

Tags: android, cardview, rippledrawable

I have multiple `CardView` in a `ListView`. These cardviews can be clicked and selected. When clicked, I want to display a `ripple`. When selected I want to change the `foreground`. Currently one of the two works. How can I make them both work at the same time?

I've tried all kind of different versions. With a mask and without, setting all states and only one. The problem is that there are 4 outcomes possible.

1: Nothing is shown
2: Only the ripple is shown
3: Only the foreground changes color after selecting the cardview
4: The ripple is shown but the foreground changes color even when pressed and doesn't change back when it is not selected.

`ListView` item:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:foreground="@drawable/rowselector"
    >
```

rowselector.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="#20000000">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/card_foreground_selector" />
</ripple>
```

card_foreground_selector.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#aae3f7ee" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#aae3f7ee" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I thought this would show a ripple when pressed and a different `foreground` color when the `CardView` is long pressed/selected. The `ripple` is currently missing.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying:

**clickable = true**

**?android:attr/selectableItemBackground**

To have the ripple effect applied to the background, while using the foreground to change the color after selecting the item?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:foreground="@drawable/card_foreground_selector">
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. Still not showing the ripple. I tried `android:drawSelectorOnTop` but that doesn't help either. `android:clickable` breaks the whole functionality. I can't click(and open the cardview) nor can I select the cardview with a long click.